# contains() method without prefix and suffix in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm stuck on a *(simple, I think)* `String` validation. I use the following method to get a text from an `EditText` which can have 420 chars and **must to contain a specific word** (whatever its place):

```
if(edittext.getText().toString().toLowerCase().contains(stringToHave)) { }
// stringToHave = the specific String
```

However, I want to improve this condition. For example, you have this:

```
String a = "This not a MetaStackOverflow question"; 
String b = "stackoverflow";
```

And you want to know if `a` contains `b` regardless is case sensitive, then, you do as follows:

```
if(a.toLowerCase().contains(b)) { }
```

This condition is *true* because indeed `a` contains `StackOverflow`. However, `a` **doesn't contain exactly** `b`, there is a prefix as `Meta`. And this is not exactly the same word.. I tried to find a way on SO and on other Java websites without result.

How can I improve `contains()` method to find only the **exact** `String` without prefix or suffix? Should I use another method *(as `containsOnly()`, I already tried it but it seems that is undefined for String, it's to check if it contains numeric/alphabetic/etc. chars)*?

**EDIT:**

Add a "two spaces" verification is very attractive and ingenious. However, if the specific text is at the end of the sentence and we add a `.` this will not work, isn't it?

```
a = "This is great. This is on StackOverflow." // false because we have "."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex here. `Matcher` class has a `find()` method, which searches for a pattern in a string. This will work:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\b" + Pattern.quote(b) + "\\b").matcher(a);
if (matcher.find()) {
    // contains
}
```

`(?i)` is case-insensitive embedded flag. `Pattern.quote()` is used to escape the regex meta-characters if any in the search string.

Comment: Yes, I saw a few `regex match` method, but same as the other, do I will have some troubles if the word is before a `,` or `.` (see my updated answer). Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @Fllo Updated answer accordingly. Use a word boundary in that case.

Comment: Works perfectly, I knew this was simple, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Use space before and after the pattern what you seek:

```
if(a.toLowerCase().contains(" " + b + " ")) { }
```

Comment: Well, yes it depends on what you want:) Use Rohit Jain's answer in that case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a case insensitive [`Pattern`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) with [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\\b` to do this:

```
String a = "This not a MetaStackOverflow question";
String b = "stackoverflow";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + b + "\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
if (p.matcher(a).find()) { }
```